# DB2: SQL0007N The character " " following "[...]" is not valid

Tags: sql, db2

I meet a very strange problem with a DB2 query.

My query looks like :

db2 "merge into A as aa using (select * from B) as bb on [...] when not matched then insert values (bb.a, bb.b, bb.c,  bb.d, bb.e) else ignore"

It's perfectly working on different databases, but not on the production database. We get the following error :

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:

DB2: SQL0007N  The character " " following "s (bb.a, bb.b, bb.c," is not valid.

SQLSTATE=42601

The problem seems to come from the white space located just after "bb.c,". We have two white spaces here, but it should not be a problem (and, indeed, it's perfectly working on the other databases. It's the first time that I see something like that).

Unfortunately I do not have a direct acess to the production database... But I can ask the client to make some operations if necessary.

Is someone does already meet this problem ?
Can it be related to the database configuration ? The query is made of 652 characters, and the problem appears after the 452nd.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the query sent from the same client? Do the other DBs and the prod db have the same character encoding? What is in the db2diag.log (client would need to look into)? ...

Comment: Yes the query is send from the same db2 client, and all the databases have the same character encoding. what do you want to check in the db2diag.log ?

Comment: How did you pass the query to your client? Not by copying/pasting it to an Outlook message or something?

Comment: Directly with the db2 UNIX command. 

The query is saved inside a .sql file (located on the server), and we launch the following command : 

db2 -ec -a -tvf SCRIPT.sql

Comment: The sql file is UNIX/ANSI encoded.

Comment: You may want to check that the script file on the production server matches the one you are testing "on different databases", e.g. by using `md5`.